# Extend Axios to accept a url of type URL

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

I'm currently working on a private TypeScript project in which I'm using Axios to send GET requests to various URLs. For convinience I'm using the NodeJS URL interface to pass on my urls but axios only works with urls of type string.

Since there's an Axios class defined in the library I tried to simply extend it and overload the GET method and calling the standard implementation with the URL unwrapped but it didn't work the way I expected it to. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I am aware of the URL.toString() method but I want to abstract it via overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just monkey-patch it:

```js
const originalGet = axios.get;
axios.get = (url) => {
  const newUrl = url instanceof URL ? url.toString() : url;
  return originalGet(newUrl);
};
```

Comment: A minor correction. You'd need to return the result of the original call.